# How to get access to an upper object properties from its lower or inner object?

Tags: python, object, get, accessibility, variable-assignment

Is there any way to get access to an upper object properties from its lower or inner object? I did it with the below code But I don't like it and I thought that maybe another solution has existed. Can you give a better suggestion?

```
class Upper():
    def __init__(self):
        self.Name='Upper'
        self.B=None
        
    def LowerObject(self,Obj): #Function that gets lowwer Object and assign Upper Object to it's variable
        self.B=Obj
        Obj.UpperObj=self
        
        

    
class Lower():
    def __init__(self):
        self.UpperObj=None
        pass
    
    def Function(self):             #Function that get Upper Object name and add something to it
        print(self.UpperObj.Name+' from Lower')
    
    
    
    
Low=Lower()             #Create an Object From Upper Class
Upp=Upper()             #Create an Object From Lower class

Upp.LowerObject(Low)    #Get lowwer Object with defined function in Upper Object

Upp.B.Function()        #lower Object Have acces to upper Object and can use upper object properties
```

Comment: I think that this depends a lot on how you use the objects. It may be just enough to stop thinking of Upper as an upper object and of Lower as a lower object and rather think of it the other way round - Upper being the lower and Lower being the upper. I mean, do you need Upper to hold a reference to Lower? Maybe it's just enough to have a reference to Upper in Lower.

Comment: Thanks @radekholy24 for your contribution on this post and I completely got your point But:
Imagine that My upper object could have different behaviors and the behavior model can be defined in many other objects and I call them lower object or behavior object. So the problem becomes in this way: when I assign the behavior object to a parent object how the behavior object can get access to the parent object properties.